# ElasticSearch: how to combine match phrase prefix with terms prefix?

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch: Which query can be used for the following result:
input query: term1, terms2
result: match term1, term2, as with match phrase prefix; match term1 as a prefix, match term2 as a prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 'bool' queries to combine multiple terms. Here is the reference link http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

An example query of what you want to do is :

```
{
  "bool" : {

    "must" : [
        {
            "prefix" : { "term1" : "prefix2" }
        },
        {
            "prefix" : { "term2" : "prefix2" }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```